# .net core 6 api bad request

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

In the past I used to do my api requests like such

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateLead(CreateLeadRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok(_handler.Value.CreateLead(request));
    }
```

But now with .net 6 you return the actual value instead of an action result:

```
    [HttpPost("create", Name = nameof(CreateLead))]
    public async Task<int> CreateLead(CreateLeadRequest request)
    {
        return await _handler.Value.CreateLead(request);
    }
```

So how do I return the bad result for null request in this case as the compiler complains that the `BadRequest` isn't an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async Task<ActionResult<int>>`.
This allows you to return HttpStatuscodes as well as the object itself.

Comment: Ah brilliant, Thanks, will accept when it lets me